# First-order nonlinear non-homogeneous ODE with multiple functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an equation of the form

$$A(x) = f(y_1, y_2)y_1' + g(y_1, y_2)y_2'$$

where $A(x)$ is an arbitrary function of $x$; $y_i\equiv y_i(x)$ are arbitrary functions of $x$; and $f$ and $g$ are functions of $y_i$.

I am confident that this is a first order differential equation since the maximum derivative of $x$ is to the first order. Also, I believe that this is non-linear since the derivatives of $y_i$ are multiplied by functions of $y_i$. Finally I believe that it is non-homogeneous since there is a function of $x$ involved.

The aim of what I am trying to do is solve this for $y_1$ since $y_2$ is known (although can still be considered arbitrary for my particular case)

I would be grateful for the following help:

1. Have I classified the differential equation correctly? (and if not why not)
2. How do you solve this differential equation?
3. How do you create an expression to evaluate $y_1(x)$

Comment: On the face of it, doesn't look separable. Do you know what $f$ and $g$ are? If so, could you please provide them? Same for $y_2.$

Comment: Since you already know $y_2$, it seems you can make it to a simple ode on $y_1$ and solve it